# vba(MsAccess) if days selected, display all dates of that days in a month

Tags: vba, ms-access

In Ms Access (VBA) , How to get all the dates of the month after selecting the certain month and weekdays?

Comment: What do you mean by 'get all the dates'? You want to make a list of dates? Where - a combobox or listbox? What do you mean by 'and weekdays'?

Comment: How to get all the dates of the month after selecting the certain month and weekdays?
VBA-Access:

"TextBox" (Input Receive Eg : FEB-2023 (MMM-YYYY))       
                                                                                                                              "Combo box" Select: Weekdays (Eg: Wednesday)
                 
                                                                                                                               
Results required in "List Box" Display : Eg : 1,8,15,22

Answer (score 0):

Build a combobox for Year-Month that has columns for year and month numbers in addition to the Year-Month text displayed to user.

Build a combobox for days that has column for weekday number in addition to the weekday name text displayed to user.

Procedure to pull dates of desired weekday and build combobox or listbox list.

```
Private Sub btnBuildList_Click()
Dim dteNext As Date, dteEnd As Date
With Me
    If IsNull(.cbxMY) Or IsNull(.cbxDy) Then
        MsgBox "Must select values in comboboxes."
    Else
        .lbxWd.RowSource = ""
        dteNext = DateSerial(.cbxMY.Column(1), .cbxMY.Column(2), 1)
        dteEnd = DateAdd("m", 1, dteNext) - 1
        Do While dteNext <= dteEnd
            If Weekday(dteNext) = Val(.cbxDy.Column(1)) Then
                .lbxWd.AddItem Day(dteNext)
            End If
            dteNext = dteNext + 1
        Loop
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a *callback* function. This will, for example, list the upcoming Mondays:

```vb
Public Function ListMondays( _
    ByRef ctl As Control, _
    ByVal Id As Long, _
    ByVal Row As Long,
    Byval Column As Long,
    Byval Code As Integer) _
    As Variant

    Dim Offset      As Integer
    Dim WeekdayDate As Date

    Select Case Code
        Case acLBInitialize     ' Initialize.
            ListMondays = True
        Case acLBOpen           ' Open.
            ListMondays = Timer ' Unique ID.
        Case acLBGetRowCount    ' Get rows.
            ListMondays = 4
        Case acLBGetColumnCount ' Get columns.
            ListMondays = 1
        Case acLBGetColumnWidth ' Get column width.
            ListMondays = -1    ' Use default width.
        Case acLBGetValue       ' Get the data.
            Offset = Abs((9 - Weekday(Date)) Mod 7) 
            WeekdayDate = DateAdd("d", Offset + 7 * row, Date) 
            ListMondays = Format(WeekdayDate, "mmmm d")     
        End Select

End Function
```

Full documentation, implementation, and a lot more code and examples, see my repository at **GitHub**:

[VBA.Callback](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Callback)

and my article series at *Experts Exchange*:

[Callback functions in Microsoft Access VBA](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/35774/Callback-functions-in-Microsoft-Access-VBA-Part-1.html?preview=KkyJtTCvMUs%3D)